# I want to get a catch curve from length frequency data, but in the process i cat get the clear catch curve and i get error messages

Tags: datagridview, django-templates

Error in round(SE_Z_lm1, 2) :
non-numeric argument to mathematical function
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In log(1 - L/Linf) : NaNs produced
2: In log(Linf - lowerLengths) : NaNs produced
3: In log(1 - L/Linf) : NaNs produced
4: In qt(0.975, sum_lm1$df[2]) : NaNs produced

I was running my codes in TropFishR that would end in a catch curve with selection ogive. but at the end i get this error message and i don't know where is my mistake. honestly im a beginner in R